# C# compiler mistakes dynamic for object

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Excel workbook project. It had been working perfectly but when I added a WPF Control to the project, things broke down.

In this project, there are lines of code like this:

```
[a dynamic variable] += [an int variable]
```

After adding the WPF control, the projected couldn't be built again, with **compiler errors in the build log, all of them to do with types and casting, like the following**:

> C:...\Ribbon1.cs(23,13,23,39): error CS0019: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

while the **error list was entirely empty**. Hovering the mouse on the relevant code, I saw this normal bubble tip:

> dynamic dynamic.operator +(dynamic left, dynamic right)

So somehow it is only the compiler that was unhappy. To troubleshoot, I removed the WPF control and could then build the project again. I find it very odd.

Opting for Windows Forms instead seems to incur no such problems but I'd rather be able to stick to WPF; writing extension methods with explicit casting is another way to get around it. But I hope someone can explain the existence of the mystery.

IDE version: Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.3)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are using please?

Comment: @luxun an example: `Globals.Sheet1.Range["E7"].Value2 += 7`. The compiler errors were all on lines like this.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx) `Value2`is not dynamic, but of type `object`. The error message seems appropriate in that case.

Comment: @Lennart You may very well be right; and the error message does disappear when I add an explicit cast: `Globals.Sheet1.Range["E7"].Value2 = (int)Globals.Sheet1.Range["E7"].Value2 + 7`. But the mystery remains - why the compiler quite happily compiles it as dynamic (and the program runs without crashing) without WPF but not with WPF (if I may put it this way).

Comment: VSTO does not support WPF natively, I believe that the error reported is not the correct one and is only linked to WPF.

Comment: Oops, the cast should have been `(double)` in a previous response to comment.